# How to stop Skype periodically asking default association for URL:Callto / URL:Skype protocol

Tags: skype, file-association

Every now and then, perhaps weekly, I'm getting a pop-up from Skype after boot asking me to set associations for the program. If this is a Skype issue or a Windows (8.1) issue I'm not sure - but it is nevertheless intrusive and I'm wondering how to stop it from asking. I do save its desired association so I do not understand why it must ask again and again.

[image: Skype callto association]

Comment: To put it simply.  Its a bug.

Comment: A Skype bug or a Windows bug?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the windows 8 version of skype installed (The "Modern" version) it may be possible that it is messing with the associations. Try uninstalling that and see if the issue persists.